# Multiplicity correction after performing non-parametric tests

Tags: nonparametric, multiple-comparisons, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

This is a theoretical question.

I am wondering if multiplicity correction is applicable in the case of non-parametric tests.

I have performed some Mann-Whitney U rank test on two independent samples using this [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html) function.

I was then thinking to apply [fdr](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.multitest.fdrcorrection.html) correction for multiplicity correction.
Does multiplicity correction makes sense in the case of non-parametric tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrections for multiple testing do not care what kinds of tests you run. When you reject a null hypothesis, you are making a decision, and corrections for multiple testing helps control the error rate of that decision.

Use it for parametric tests; use it for nonparametric tests; use it if you mix the two. The control has to do with the resulting decision.

Comment: clear thanks for the answer.